# How can I check if all variables are different?

Tags: javascript, variables, math, logic

Is it possible to check if all variables are different from each other in another way than this?

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4;

if(a != b && a != c && a != d && b != a && b != c && b != d && c != a && c != b && c != d && d != a && d != b && d != c){
  //All numbers are different
}
```

for example

```
if(a != b != c != d){

}
```

Comment: Normally, this questions arises when your data are structured (an array, an object, etc.). The first step here is probably to have a proper design for your data.

Comment: I'd advise you to make an array of the variables and loop through them!
If you really want to stay with the major if case, You could go for some if else if construction.

Answer (score 6):

You can store them all in an object and check if the number of keys is equal to the number of variables used, like this

```
var dummy = {};
dummy[a] = true;
dummy[b] = true;
dummy[c] = true;
dummy[d] = true;
console.log(Object.keys(dummy).length === 4);
```

If the values are different, then a new key will be created every time and the number of keys will be equal to the number of variables used.

Comment: This is very inventive and low impact.

Answer (score 2):

As Denys Séguret commented, if you have a proper structure for your data then it will be possible to do it in a more elegant way.

However, with what you have you can still simplify as you can remove duplicate checks.

For example, you check that a != b and then later that b != a. Those two checks are effectively the same, just in a different order.

Removing all duplicates gives you...

```
if(a != b && a != c && a != d && b != c && b != d && c != d)
```

Which is somewhat simpler, although you'd still be better off structuring your data.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to `push` the variables in an array:

```js
var a = 1,
  b = 2,
  c = 3,
  d = 4;

var arr = [];
arr.push(a);
arr.push(b);
arr.push(c);
arr.push(d);
var sorted_arr = arr.sort(); // You can define the comparing function here. 
// JS by default uses a crappy string compare.
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
  if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
    results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
  }
}

alert(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using arrays

```
var a =10, b = 20, c=30, d =40, e =50;
alert(isVariablesDifferent(a,b,c,d,e));

function isVariablesDifferent(){
    var params = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
        if(params.lastIndexOf(params[i]) !== i){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of the variable. Iterate the entire from first to last element and compare or otherwise hardcode like below.

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4; 

if(a != b && a != c && a != d && b != c && b != d && c != d)
alert('all the variables are unique');
```

Kindly refer my sample code in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/parthipans/fNPvf/15217/

Comment: Other than using symmetry to skip half of OP's comparisons, does this really do anything?  Why not show us the code for the first suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that without context it should be hard to provide a quality answer, but since ECMA-Script 5 there's an `Array.prototype.every` function to check if all array items do conform a boolean expression. That is, you can express the same problem this way:

```js
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4; 

if(
  [b, c, d].every(function(someVar) { return someVar != a; })
  && [a, c, d].every(function(someVar) { return someVar != b })
  && [a, b, d].every(function(someVar) { return someVar != c })
  && [a, b, c].every(function(someVar) { return someVar != d })
) {
  alert("all different!");
}
```

Or check how you can even simplify this implementing a `different(...)` function to `Array.prototype` (or you can implement it as a property of some custom object or as just a regular procedural function...).

```js
Array.prototype.different = function() {
  var results = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
     // This is to clone the array so we don't modify the source one
     var arrayCopy = [].concat(this);
    
     // This drops the variable value to check and returns it
     var varValueToCheck = arrayCopy.splice(i, 1);
    
     // Then we use every to check that every variable value doesn't
     // equal current variable value to compare
     results.push(arrayCopy.every(
       function(varValue) {
         return varValue != varValueToCheck;
       })
     );
  }
  
  // Once we've got all boolean results, we call every() on
  // boolean results array to check that all items are TRUE
  // (i.e. no variable equals to other ones!)
  return results.every(function(result) { return result; });
};

// This should avoid that other libs could re-define "different"
// function, and also it should avoid for..in or forEach issues
// finding unexpected functions, as this function will be hidden 
// when iterating Array.prototype
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "different", {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false
});

var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4; 

// Simplified check! 
if([a, b, c, d].different()) {
   alert("also all different!!!");  
}
```

Now the issue might be if simplifying an `if` statement like yours with something like my proposal is an overkill or not, but this will depend on your actual use case.

Answer (score 0):

I made a function for testing this for you.  This could be costly with large data sets though.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Luqm8z7b/

```
function uniqueTest(ary){
 for(var i=ary.pop(); ary.length > 0;i=ary.pop()){
  for(var j = 0; j < ary.length; j++){
   if(i === j) return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}

var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4;
var list = [];
list.push(a, b, c, d);
console.log(uniqueTest(list));
```